# Change field in a class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, architecture

I have a binary tree class `BTree` that is working good and I don't change anything there.

```
class BTreeNode {
private:
    vector<string> data;
    BTreeNode *parent = nullptr;
    BTreeNode *leftChild = nullptr;
    BTreeNode *rightChild = nullptr;

public:
    BTreeNode();

    BTreeNode(vector<string> noteData);

    // getters and setters...
};

class BTree {
private:
    BTreeNode *root = nullptr;

public:
    BTree();

    void add(vector<string> newNodeValue);

    // other methods
};
```

But now I wanna create a new red-black tree class `RBTree`. I thought that make it by inheritance would be a good idea.

The first problem takes place in nodes of a red-black tree. They have an additional field - colour. If the class of nodes of a red-black tree `RBTreeNode` inherits `BTreeNode` then the problem is that getters and setters of `BTreeNode` returns an `BTreeNode` object but I need `RBTreeNode`.

```
class RBTreeNode : public BTreeNode {
public:
    enum Colour { BLACK, RED };
private:
    Colour colour;

public:
    // constructors, getters and setters...
}
```

The second problem is the `root` of `BTree` because in the new `RBTree` class that `root` should be the `RBTreeNode` type.

So, is there a way to solve it in OOP way? Or should I change my approach?

Comment: Since you know for sure that each of the pointers points to `BTreeNode`, downcasting would not be such an evil solution. But it would be probably easier to use (template) composition and delegate calls from `BTree` to concrete implementations instead of using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess inheritance is not a good way for this problem. Red-Black tree node must have color variable and if you use inheritance u could't keep that value in correct way. My Red-Black Tree node is like that:

```
struct RB_Tree_Node {
    vector<string> data;
    bool color;  // black = 0, red = 1;
    Node* left, * right, * parent;
    Node* sibling(Node* x) {
        if (x->parent == NULL)
            return NULL;

        if (x->parent->left)
            return x->parent->right;

        return x->parent->left;
    }
    bool hasRedChild() {
        return (left != NULL && left->color == 1) || (right != NULL && right->color == 1);
    }
};
```